# using C# to send httprequest in order to get access token in SSIS

Tags: marketing-cloud, c#, .net

How to use Salesforce Marketing Cloud API to connect with my SQL server database. I need to use C# to do HTTP POST request to acquire an access token, but I have no idea how to do it. I need to run this sample code in C#:

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "clientId": "gyjzvytv7ukqtfn3x2qdyfsn",
  "clientSecret": "************"
}
```

Also, does marketing cloud support .net 3.5? Or any tool I can use?

I am using SSIS 2008r2, I want to write c# code to make an api call to the exact Target API to connect to SQL server database. Because I want to pull data from SQL server to marketing cloud. I didn't find any article about using SSIS to connect Marketing cloud.....

Comment: Can you clarify which system is doing the calling? Do you want Marketing Cloud to call out to your database? Or do you want to write C# code that makes an API call to the Exact Target API?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [C# Fuel SDK](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/csharp/getting-started-with-the-csharp-sdk.html) provided for Marketing Cloud that should make integration's from .NET a lot easier.

The [ET_Client](https://github.com/salesforcefuel/FuelSDK-csharp#et_client-class) has parameters for `clientId` and `clientSecret`.